# Maven build failure when i create a maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

Hello i want to write a plug in for jenkins and need maven.
So i install maven and checked the installation with this command in cmd(windows 7):

```
mvn --version
```

The output ist this

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 
Maven home: C:\Program Files\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

So maven ist correctly installed.
But when i trying to create a project with this command:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.itcuties -DartifactId=test
```

i  get this Building failure

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.084 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-10T14:20:49+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
in this directory (C:\Users\meyers). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.


 [ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN
/MissingProject
Exception
```

I read the documantation but it does not help.
I configured maven from this tutorial

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWstBgxcoXw
```

Comment: Go into the directory where the pom.xml has been generated...and try again `mvn package` ...

Comment: I dont have a pom.xml data. How can i create it, when i am writting mvn -cpu hpi:create  there comes also a building failure

Comment: If you like to call Maven a pom file is needed...Why would you like to call `mvn hpi:create` if so you need to be in the folder where a pom.xml file is located...

Answer (score 0):

1. This command : `mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.itcuties -DartifactId=test` need pom.xml
2. To write a plug in for jenkins , see official documentation https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-Eclipse